# An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused - docker - symfony

Tags: docker, symfony

My code (symfony 5.4) fails to persist data to the database. Here's my setup:-

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
...
#MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3316:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pink
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network
...
```

**.env**

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:password@db:3316/pink"
```

**ProductController.php**

```
#[Route('/product/create', name: 'product_create')]
    public function createProduct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();

        $product = new Product();
        $product->setName('Keyboard');
        $product->setPrice(1999);
        $product->setDescription('Ergonomic and stylish!');

        // tell Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
        $entityManager->persist($product);

        // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
        $entityManager->flush();

        return new Response('Saved new product with id '.$product->getId());

    }
```

The database (docker) container is up and running fine. Here's a test, with success:-

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --password=password pink --port=3316 --ssl-mode=disabled
```

In my `.env` file I've replaced the string `127.0.0.1` with my docker container name as above: `db` .

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out we need to use the default port number for database connections i.e. `3306` . Full db string like thus:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:password@db:3306/pink"
```

I still don't fully understand the idea of internal/external & visibility of port numbers in docker containers

```
db:
    ...
    ports:
      - "3316:3306"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on working with Docrine WSL2 , I had to add this line in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 db
```

And use this config in `.env` file:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:password@db:3306/my_database_name?serverVersion=8.0.3&charset=utf8mb4"
```